# Determine whether Derby network server is running a file system or memory database

Tags: java, maven, derby

Before my maven build's integration test phase I start a derby server using the `derby-maven-plugin` from carlspring, and afterwards I shut it down using the same plugin.

According to Derby's [Setting attributes for the database connection URL](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefattrib24612.html) docs:

> Note: Attributes are not parsed for correctness. If you pass in an incorrect attribute or corresponding value, it is simply ignored.

Based on the [create=true attribute](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefattrib26867.html) documentation I created a URL for an in-memory database to run on the network server:

```
jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/memory:tariff;create=true
```

*If incorrect attributes are ignored, how can I check that my tests are running against an in-memory DB on the network server?*

Comment: Are you asking: how can you tell if the database is correctly operating as an in-memory database? Well, you could (a) see if it persists past the shutdown, or (b) look in your filesystem to see if there are files in the 'tariff' directory of your network server. Perhaps I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [derby-maven-plugin](https://github.com/carlspring/derby-maven-plugin) keeps it's database on the file system under `target/derby`. Once the build has finished, you can connect to that database with a JDBC client and check the data yourself.

I'm glad to see someone is finding this plugin useful! Let me know, if you have any other questions, as I'm the main developer of the plugin.